# Session works properly on original but not on loop copies

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This works good with out a loop but with a loop the first one works but the second one can't set a PHP session value like the first one so how can I get the loop copy to work like the first one meaning being able to set a PHP session value.

***NOTE: THIS IS *NOT A HTML FORM* THIS IS COSTUME CODE THAT me and my friend MADE FROM a tutorial THAT ACTS LIKE A FORM TO SET A SESSION VALUE.***

tutorial source: https://www.formget.com/submit-form-using-ajax-php-and-jquery/#

I don't want to use a form don't ask me why it's personal so how can I fix this where the loop copy can also set a session value of a session variable i'm saying this because only the first one is able to do that and the second one can't set a session value like the first one.

[.gif Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAj09.gif)

**code**

*submit_session.php*

```
<?php 
session_start(); 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Simulated Form</title> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

//This section converts the HTML id's in the form div into form values

$(document).ready(function(){  
$("#execute").click(function(){
var execute= $("#execute").val();
var name= $("#name").val();
var age= $("#age").val();

var dataString = 'execute='+ execute + '&name='+ name + '&age='+ age;


//AJAX code to submit the simulated form.

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "submit_session.php",
data: dataString
});
});
});
</script>

<style>

.form {
background-color: gold;
width: 200px;
margin: auto;
border-radius: 5px;
padding-top: 5px;
}

.set-value{
background: blue;
padding: 1px 4px;
text-decoration: none;
border: 1px solid gray;
color: white;
margin: auto;
display: block;
width: 100px;
text-align: center;
border-radius: 5px;
}

  .name-input {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
  }

  .age-input {
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
  }


</style>

</head>

<body>
<?php

//Generate more than one copy of the simulated form
for ($loop = 0; $loop <= 1; $loop++) {

?>

<br> 

<!--The simulated form-->

<div class="form">
<p style='text-align: center;'>Simulated form</p> 
<input type="text" id="name" class='name-input' required="required" placeholder='Name' autocomplete="off">
<br>
<input type="text" id="age" class='age-input' required="required" placeholder='Age' autocomplete="off">
<br>
<!-- Simulated form submit button -->  
<a  class="set-value" id="execute" href="view-session-values.php">Set value</a>
<br>
</div>

<?php

echo $loop;
}

//Set session values from a simulated form

if(isset($_POST['execute'])){
$name = $_POST['name'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
if($check=1){
$_SESSION['name']=$name;
$_SESSION['age']=$age;
echo "<script>window.open('_self')</script>";
}
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

*view-session-values.php*

```
<?php
session_start();
$name = $_SESSION['name'];
$age = $_SESSION['age'];
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

  #set-new-session-value {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }

  #destroy-session-value{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }

</style>
</head>

<body>

<!--This section is based on choosing session options -->
<br>
<a id='set-new-session-value' href="submit_session">Set new session value</a>
<a id='destroy-session-value' href="destroy_session.php">Destroy session value</a>
<br>

<!--This section is where the set session values are shown-->
<p><?php echo $name; ?></p
<p><?php echo $age; ?></p>  

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is this a copy paste error, or you have in your code: `if($check=1)`

Comment: I add 2  instead of 1 to if($check=1) and the code did not work so i left it how it was but this works good with actual html forms meaning all the loop copies of the html form where able to set a session value but I rather use this fake simulated form method to be able to set a session value but ever since I done that it does not work with loops so i'm refusing to use actual forms because this method is beneficial to me what I want to do. So what else do you think can be the problem? Because if I try to use the second one it only display the first one set session values.

Comment: I was just curious why that if statement was a single equals anyhow, as it will always result in 'true'. Just a curious way you are doing it. I doubt its the cause of your troubles, because the way you are going about this, is very odd (firing off an ajax, AND a href at the same time). Its just all, curious. I'd rewrite it differently, but I don't think it would help you.